# ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para juntar dataframes y filtrar fechas en python?

Tags: filtro

El problema es el siguiente:

Requiero optimizar un portafolio de inversión:

Tengo 4 activos diferentes en un data frame, pero con fechas distintas.

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que estos 4 activos se filtren por fechas? . Es decir la primera fecha del primer activo  empieza en el año 1977, el segundo el 1980, y así sucesivamente, los 4 terminan  en 2020.

Puse este línea de código:

portafolio=c.merge(pkg.merge(amat.merge(spx, on= "Date"),on="Date"),on="Date")
portafolio.head()

Y el resultado lo recibo solo con los nombres de los encabezados, pero sin datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

para juntar los dataframe puedes utilizar la función `.concat()` que recibe como parametro una lista de dataframe y retorna la fusión de estos.

Ejemplo

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['12/12/2020', '01/07/2018']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [100, 20], 'col2': ['12/12/2010','05/01/2020']})
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2])

merged
```

Para filtrar por fechas necesitaremos tener la columna en dicho formato, para ello utilizaremos la función `.to_datetime` de pandas y luego, simplemente filtraremos.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['12/12/2020', '01/07/2018']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [100, 20], 'col2': ['12/12/2010','05/01/2020']})

merged = pd.concat([df1, df2])

merged

merged['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['col2'])
merged = merged[merged['col2'] > '01/01/2020']
merged
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, procura seleccionarla como mejor respuesta para ayudar a más personas en el futuro. éxito!